# Odd result in php

Tags: php, string

I have found a problem with the following lines of PHP code:

```
$stripped = 'some string';    
$stripped = substr($stripped, 0, strrpos($stripped, ' '));
```

The intent was to strip off the last token of text. When I traced the execution of the code, I found that it was not working. In order to make it work, I had to change the code to the following:

```
$stripped = 'some string'; 
$truncate_length = strrpos($stripped, ' ');
$stripped = substr($stripped, 0, $truncate_length);
```

Why would the first version of this code not work? I have never felt it necessary before to avoid function composition like the above example shows as necessary.

Comment: `I found that it was not working`. It strips last _word_ of strings. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Your first piece of code seems to work just fine. Please elaborate on how it does not work as expected. Also, remember to turn error reporting on while in development, to make sure you notice any errors, and var_dump() is very useful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

It does work. Maybe a misspelling ?

Also, remember that if there is no `' '` (space) found with strrpos, you will get `false` as return value and will kill $stripped